# YouTube embedded thumbnail blurry in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube

When placing YouTube embed code on my site it works fine until I put it in a Bootstrap Modal, when the thumbnail loaded is the default and looks all blurry.

I noticed this initially on a WordPress site using Bootstrap 3. I wasn't sure if the problem was other code on the site, but I created a dummy area with raw Bootstrap 3 templates and put the embed code directly on the page which loads the correct thumbnail resolution, but when putting it in a modal the thumbnail is very pixelated - it looks like it loads the version that is only 120px wide.

I've seen similar posts to this, but these describe a problem no matter where they place the code. In this case it happens only in the modal.

I did try changing the way the modal is initially hidden, so instead of display:none, I tried position:absolute; left:40000px; to hide it off the page instead and this seemed to make a difference, but no way ideal.

However this makes me think the issue is that when initially loading the page, if YouTube detects that the embed code is in HTML with display:none styling then it loads the smallest thumbnail.

Is there a way to refresh the iFrame on loading the modal maybe? This is the basic code I've used where you can see the difference between the thumbnail of the embedded code on the page and that in the modal:

```
<iframe width="872" height="491" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_oujaqNoNUQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<iframe width="872" height="491" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_oujaqNoNUQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I started getting these when I add the embed inside a spoiler. It's also happening within YouTube itself, when you click on share  > embed > show more. I noticed this today.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue with Chrome and IE. And yes, it was because the hidden modal had no width so the thumbnail served was the smallest (100px X 100px). We reloaded the iframe source once the modal opened. Yes, there was a quick "flicker" from the old blurry thumbnail to the new correct one, but it fixed the issue.

```
$(".modal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
 var $if = $(e.delegateTarget).find('iframe');
 var src = $if.attr("src");
 $if.attr("src", '/empty.html');
 $if.attr("src", src);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Brett - yes we have it reloading now and like you said it causes a slight flicker but works! Thanks for your reply!